# Is there a way to map an iterator to its container?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

Suppose I have three vectors A, B and C of same type, and I am given an iterator for the vector container, how do I find which container does it belong to?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your design is broken, rethink it.

The entire point of iterators is to abstract away from containers (and other collections of data), you cannot just reverse the abstraction.

Comment: I understand (of course after testing in a code) this was a bad design choice. What made me curious was that the debugger was able to detect iterator from different vector containers being compared, and made me think may be there is a way to map back iterator to container. So I just wanted to know if anyone else knew such techniques.. Thanks!

Comment: @user6386155 An implementation / debugger / we. is of course allowed to track what range an iterator belongs to, but in general, it is a one way street.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering your question, you can check like this:

```
vector<T>::iterator it = ...;
if (it >= A.begin() && it < A.end()) // it is in vector A
if (it >= B.begin() && it < B.end()) // or in vector B
if (it >= C.begin() && it < C.end()) // and here in vector C
```

This only works because `vector` uses a random access iterator, and won't hold for plenty of other containers like `map` and `list`. As @Baum mit Augen says, you should redesign to avoid this. Perhaps you should pass a reference to the vector you want along with the iterator?

Comment: one problem is when you change a vector, you may hold invalid iterator

Comment: The more immediate issue is that comparing iterators from different containers invokes Undefined Behavior. So this is not really legal. (Will probably work though, never tried it.)

Comment: Fwiw. libstdc++'s debug mode does complain. (Rightfully so.) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36d6c1107be7b54f

Comment: @BaummitAugen is this UB too? `std::cout << std::less<decltype(&*it)>()(&*it, &*begin(b));`

Comment: @SCFrench Yes, `std::less` invokes `operator<` unless specialized, which is not the case here. So again, both iterators compared must be valid iterators "of the same range". (For technical definition of that, look for "reachable").

Comment: @BaummitAugen According to cppreference.com, "A specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields a total order, even if the built-in operator< does not." Wouldn't `&*it` yield a pointer if `it` was a vector iterator?

Comment: a) *"Wouldn't &*it yield a pointer if it was a vector iterator?"* Yes, unless the iterator's value type overloads the unary `operator&` to do something different. b) You can't even compare pointers from different arrays iirc, and I suspect `std::less` won't fix that. If it's not asked somewhere on SO already, you can proly make some rep by asking a language-lawyer question about that.